# Json.NET create schema for dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, jsonschema

I have a class `Letter` :

```
public class Letter
{
    public string p1 {get; set;}
    public string p2 {get; set;}
    public List<string> l1 {get; set;}
    public List<string> l2 {get; set;}
}
```

And i have json file:

```
{
    "A": 
    {
        "p1": "",
        "p2": "",
        "l1": ["", "", ..., ""],
        "l2": ["", "", ..., ""]
    }
    "B": {...}
    ...
}
```

For now i deserialize json with `Json.NET` from `NewtonSoft` like this:

```
var alphabet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<char, Letter>>(jsonString);
```

So i can refer to values like this: `alphabet["A"]`

Now i want to check, is `jsonString`, which i want to deserialize is valid.

I found some examples how to read `JsonSchema` from file, or how to generate it in code. But i can't find out, how generate shema for my example of json file.

Can anyone help me?

P.S.

For now i do it like this. Is this best way?

```
...
var schemaGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator();
var schemaForLetter = schemaGenerator.Generate(typeof (Letter));
var schema = new JSchema
{
    Type = JSchemaType.Object,
    Properties =
    {
        { "A", schemaForLetter },
        { "B", schemaForLetter },
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Comment: why not just `var schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Dictionary<string, Letter>))`?

Comment: @AlekseyL. please write answer to this question, so i could check it as right answer.
I think if user define his json not only with alphabet symbols, it has been more right then first conclusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate schema from the type you're deserializing to. For example:

```
var schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Dictionary<string, Letter>))
```

Comment: And i rebuild my json file. I think, using of: `"p1": {"a": [], "b":[], ...}` is match more better. Thanks for help